# sqlldr error in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, sql-loader

Currently, I am using `sqlldr  userid= {user}/{pass}@{SID}` to load the file into database, and this comment is in a bash file.

> The password is generated by a third lib framework.

But, I found that sometimes I got the following error,

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/config/uat/  
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin 
sqlldr  userid=M_UAT/YAu8D=5r@My_UAT  
ERR>LRM-00116: syntax error at 'M_UAT/YAu8D' following '='
```

I found that there is a special character `=` in the password,

I checked something, seems sqlplus can avoid this exception by `userid= ={user}/\"{pass}\"@{SID}`

But sqlldr cannot.

Does anyone have an idea here?

Comment: did you try `userid="M_UAT/YAu8D=5r@My_UAT"`?

Comment: Tried, the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlplus` makes a connection with the username and password in quotes. The sqlloader(`sqlldr`) connects to the database only if the name is written without quotes.
The password can contain `@!=` characters only in quotation marks, for example

```
password=\"YAu8D=5r\"
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"
```

**Example 1**

```
username=HR
password=\"YAu8D=5r\"
```

Change password

```
oracle@esmd:~> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jul 2 13:39:10 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter user hr identified by "YAu8D=5r" ;

User altered.

SQL> exit
```

Test connect sqlplus

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"HR\"
password=\"YAu8D=5r\"

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual
@ulcase1.sql
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput


oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case2.sh
username: "HR"
password: "YAu8D=5r"
USER is "HR"
```

Test  SQL*loader script test_sqlldr.sh

```
oracle@esmd:~> more test_sqlldr.sh
#!/bin/sh

username=hr
password=\"YAu8D=5r\"

sqlldr userid=$username/$password  control=ulcase2.ctl log=log.log
```

Test  SQL*loader

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_sqlldr.sh

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Jul 2 13:46:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7
oracle@esmd:~>
```

Test network connection sqlldr

```
oracle@esmd:~> more test_sqlldr.sh
#!/bin/sh

username=hr
password=\"YAu8D=5r\"

sqlldr userid=$username/$password@esmd  control=ulcase2.ctl log=log.log


oracle@esmd:~> ./test_sqlldr.sh

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Jul 2 13:53:24 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7
```

**Example 2**

```
username=HR
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"
```

Script for connection testing sqlplus

```
#!/bin/sh

username=HR
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual;
@ulcase1.sql
exit;
EOF
)
echo $testoutput
```

Test connect sqlplus

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case2.sh
username: "HR"
password: "@!YAu8D=5r@"
USER is "HR" 03-07-2018 12:44 Test passed
```

Test  SQL*loader script test_sqlldr.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

username=HR
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"

sqlldr userid=$username/$password  control=ulcase2.ctl log=log.log
```

Test  SQL*loader

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_sqlldr.sh

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Jul 3 12:48:53 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 7
```

**Example 3**

```
 username=\"HR\"
 password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"
```

Script for connection testing sqlplus

```
#!/bin/sh

username=\"HR\"
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"

echo username:  $username
echo password:  $password

testoutput=$(sqlplus -s $username/$password  << EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
show user
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')||' Test passed' from dual;
@ulcase1.sql
exit;
EOF
)

echo $testoutput
```

Test connect sqlplus

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_Upper_case2.sh
username: "HR"
password: "@!YAu8D=5r@"
USER is "HR" 03-07-2018 12:51 Test passed


oracle@esmd:~> more test_sqlldr.sh
#!/bin/sh

username=\"HR\"
password=\"@!YAu8D=5r@\"

sqlldr userid=$username/$password  control=ulcase2.ctl log=log.log
```

Test  SQL*loader

```
oracle@esmd:~> ./test_sqlldr.sh
LRM-00112: multiple values not allowed for parameter 'userid'

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Jul 3 12:54:42 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-100: Syntax error on command-line
```